# How to override TOMCAT Oracle ojdbc14 driver in the application?

Tags: spring, maven-2, jdbc, jndi, tomcat5.5

The TOMCAT server is using an Oracle 9G ojdbc14 driver to its jndi connections in the /common/lib folder.

My web application uses Maven + Spring and I'm getting the dataSource using Spring jndi features.

I'm trying to bypass TOMCAT old ojdbc14 driver with a newer one (ojdbc14 10.2.0.4.0).
I've tried putting the jars in the WEB-INF/lib folder as a project dependency, but it doesn't work the application keeps using the old oracle driver that is in the TOMCAT folder.

I'm trying to bypass the TOMCAT oracle driver because I cannot update it to the newest version because there are lots of other projects using it.

Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work, Tomcat won't use the JDBC driver of your webapp to create a connection pool. In other words, you'll have to either replace the version in `common/lib` or to use a standalone connection pool at the application level.